# How to Setup Chuztpah with TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, chutzpah

I'm trying to include code coverage report into TFS build for my C#/TypeScript project. So I did the same as this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/enabling-javascripttypescript-code-coverage-brett-jacobson). But I'm getting TFS build error because report file was not found because there is no build task to create that report.

So my question is How to setup TFS build to generate a report from chutzpah.json file?

Comment: Could you please share the build definition settings (build steps) and the build logs for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Chutzpah NuGet package to your project using the `Package Manager Console`. Follow the steps in below article to install and configure the Chutzpah:

[Testing your JavaScript using Chutzpah and Visual Studio Team Services](http://Testing%20your%20JavaScript%20using%20Chutzpah%20and%20Visual%20Studio%20Team%20Services)

Make sure you correctly configured the “Test” task:

> 1. Set the test assembly to match the JavaScript test naming
>      convention.
> 2. Make sure that point to the Chutzpah test adapter, the NuGet package
>      that you installed earlier.

Also please note that “**Publish Code Coverage Results**” task only supports to show the code coverage result published with "**JaCoCo**" or "**Cobertura**" format for now. The "**Summary file**", you need to give the path of your summary file. You could give a UNC path or a local path.

[image]

Comment: @Mhd Have you resolved the issue by above answer? any update?